# "Rename Application Package" stops android cordova app from accessing Internet

Tags: android, cordova, adt

I lost the keystore for an android app so I have to use a different bundle identifier (e.g. was com.domain and try com.domain.www or com.domain.appname) When I use "Rename Application Package" to change it to something else and Run the app on a phone the internet connection to the app stops working. If I rename it back to the original the internet connection for the app works again. No "problems" seem to come up in eclipse at all.

When it says "Do you want to update your launch configurations" I've been saying "yes".

Comment: Internet connection stops working? Or some internet checking functionality which was based on a plugin, that stops working?

Comment: Check in manifest file change the changes are done or not..

Comment: The app allows the user to log in, etc, using jquery. When the package name is the original one it works and if I try to change it it stops working. Maybe there is the old name in there somewhere. BTW android seems to refer to the app as : au.com.example.TheAppName... (it adds it onto the end)

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml gets updated properly.

Comment: `<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.checkhere"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >` check here " com.example.checkhere "

Comment: Can you please post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by making sure `com.domain` was changed to `com.domain.appname` in all files. Some required it to be changed to `com.domain.appname.AppName`.

I had to use `appname` because I had already used `com.domain` for an app that someone lost the password to the keystore.

I'm not sure which ones the ADT successfully changed....

\.cordova\config.json

```
{"id":"com.domain.appname","name":"AppName"}
```

\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10006" android:versionName="1.0.6" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.domain.appname" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.domain.appname.AppName" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
```

\platforms\android\assets\www\config.xml

```
<widget id="com.domain.appname" version="1.0.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

\platforms\android\gen\com\domain\appname\BuildConfig.java

```
package com.domain.appname;
```

\platforms\android\gen\com\domain\appname\R.java

```
package com.domain.appname;
```

\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml

```
<widget id="com.domain.appname" version="1.0.6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

\platforms\android\src\com\domain\appname\AppName.java

```
package com.domain.appname;
```